When choosing an option in the select I have to disable the non-matching selects
I need to disable mismatched selects based on the option of a fixed select.
In particular I have the select 'Flatlist'; in each option of this select I pass a 'data-option' attribute which corresponds to the 'data-select' attribute of the selects with names "cars", "pets", "languages".
The code below works almost fine. I'm having a small problem!
When I try to select a second option from the 'Flatlist' select again, all three selects are disabled, while I want it to have the same behavior as if I clicked on this select the first time.


document.getElementById('flatlist').addEventListener('change', function () {
    let attribute_select = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-option");

    document.querySelectorAll('.selects').forEach(sel => {
        if (sel.getAttribute('data-select') !== attribute_select) {
            sel.value = "";
            sel.disabled = true;
        }
    })
});
<label for="flatlist">Flatlist:</label>
    <select name="flatlist" id="flatlist">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option data-option="car" value="choosecars">I choose the select cars</option>
        <option data-option="pet" value="choosepets">I choose the select pets</option>
        <option data-option="language" value="chooselanguages">I choose the select languages</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select data-select="car" name="cars" id="cars" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>
    <select data-select="pet" name="pets" id="pet-select" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
        <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
        <option value="spider">Spider</option>
        <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
    </select>

    <label for="lang">Language</label>
    <select data-select="language" name="languages" id="lang" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="golang">Golang</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="c#">C#</option>
        <option value="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="erlang">Erlang</option>
    </select>



I hope I have been clear enough in explaining the problem. However the above code is working, easy to understand this problem!
Thanks to those who will help me!

You're only disabling options, you're never enabling the other options. Add an else block that enables the option.

@Barmar Can you show me with an answer?

You need to re-enable the selects that may have been disabled.
You should also disable all of the other selects initially in the HTML. They should only be enabled when the user selects the appropriate option from the first select.


document.getElementById('flatlist').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let attribute_select = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.option;

  document.querySelectorAll('.selects').forEach(sel => {
    if (sel.getAttribute('data-select') !== attribute_select) {
      sel.value = "";
      sel.disabled = true;
    } else {
      sel.disabled = false;
    }
  })
});

function changeSelect() {}
<label for="flatlist">Flatlist:</label>
<select name="flatlist" id="flatlist">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option data-option="car" value="choosecars">I choose the select cars</option>
  <option data-option="pet" value="choosepets">I choose the select pets</option>
  <option data-option="language" value="chooselanguages">I choose the select languages</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select data-select="car" name="cars" id="cars" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()" disabled>
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>
<select data-select="pet" name="pets" id="pet-select" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()" disabled>
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
  <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
  <option value="spider">Spider</option>
  <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="lang">Language</label>
<select data-select="language" name="languages" id="lang" class="selects" onchange="changeSelect()" disabled>
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="php">PHP</option>
  <option value="java">Java</option>
  <option value="golang">Golang</option>
  <option value="python">Python</option>
  <option value="c#">C#</option>
  <option value="C++">C++</option>
  <option value="erlang">Erlang</option>
</select>




perfect, I also tried to put this initially but it didn't work.. I had another active function that didn't allow me to execute the code perfectly

This almost looks like event in the change handler is getting hoisted perhaps...maybe my brain is tired.

I had copied that part from the original post, and I didn't notice that it was missing the event parameter to the listener function. It works in browsers other than Firefox because they have a global event variable that holds the current event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

You need to add the event to the function(event) part and a bit more.
You probably want to enable if you chose again so I added some events for enable/disable and there is no onchange="changeSelect()" so I removed that.


const eventDisableMe = new Event("disableMe");
const eventEnableMe = new Event("enableMe");
const selContainer = document.body.querySelector('.selects-container');
const selectThings = selContainer.querySelectorAll('select.selects');
selectThings.forEach((selT) => {
  selT.addEventListener("disableMe", disableSelect);
  selT.addEventListener("enableMe", enableSelect);
});

function disableSelect(event) {
  event.target.value = "";
  event.target.disabled = true;
}

function enableSelect(event) {
  event.target.value = "";
  event.target.disabled = false;
}

document.getElementById('flatlist')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset
    let myChoiceData = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.optiontarget;
    //ref delegation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation 
    const selContainer = document.body.querySelector('.selects-container');
    const selectThings = selContainer.querySelectorAll('select.selects');
    Array.from(selectThings).forEach(selE => {
      selE.dispatchEvent(eventEnableMe);
    });
    const chosenFew = Array.from(selectThings)
      .filter(sel => sel.dataset.select != myChoiceData);
    chosenFew.forEach(few => {
      few.dispatchEvent(eventDisableMe);
    });
  });
<label for="flatlist">Flatlist:</label>
<select name="flatlist" id="flatlist">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option data-optiontarget="car" value="choosecars">I choose the select cars</option>
  <option data-optiontarget="pet" value="choosepets">I choose the select pets</option>
  <option data-optiontarget="language" value="chooselanguages">I choose the select languages</option>
</select>
<div class="selects-container">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select data-select="car" name="cars" id="cars" class="selects">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>
  <select data-select="pet" name="pets" id="pet-select" class="selects">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
  </select>

  <label for="lang">Language</label>
  <select data-select="language" name="languages" id="lang" class="selects">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="golang">Golang</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="c#">C#</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="erlang">Erlang</option>
  </select>
</div>




This is not necessarily better or worse that other answers here but more another option to do what you desire.
